# How do I pass a std::string as a constructor argument and store the C string it holds in a void pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a constructor that accepts a `const` reference to a `std::string` object and is supposed to store the `std::string`'s internal C string in a `void` pointer member variable. However, my program segfaults when the `void` pointer is used, and `gdb` says that the pointer is pointing to address `0x01`. Here is my source:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(const std::string& str);
        void* getData();

    private:
        Foo(void* newData);
        void* data;
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
Foo::Foo(const std::string& str)
    : Foo(str.c_str())
{
    //nothing
}

void* Foo::getData() {
    return data;
}

Foo::Foo(void* newData)
    : data(newData)
{
    //nothing
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int func(void* data);

int main() {
    Foo f("bar");

    func(f.getData()); //segfault here

    return 0;
}

int func(void* data) {
    std::string str = (char*)data;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a very bad idea. Why the `void*`?

Comment: It is probably better to store a copy of the `std::string` in the class and return a `void*` to its internal *char array* when needed.

Answer (score 2):

The string that is constructed from `"bar"` no longer exists when you call `f.getData()`, so the pointer to its internal character array is no longer valid. The string is just constructed for the function call and is destructed again before the rest of the `main`-function is executed.  The segfault happens when you dereference the invalid pointer.

Try the following instead:

```
const std::string str("bar");
Foo f(str);
```

This way, the string is still in scope when the data is needed.

---

Apart from that, the overall approach is not advisable. Better not use `void*` pointers and raw pointers if possible, or at least manage them safely within an object. Your problem already makes clear why this kind of pointer usage is unsafe and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Foo f("bar");

You are passing a reference to a temporary value to the constructor. The lifetime of the object is only inside the constructor. So the void *data points to a deleted memory.

To be more precise, if you are not aware, you may want to know the difference between ***l-value*** and ***r-value*** in C++.

eg) int a = 5

Here **a** is l-value and **5** is the r-value. Simply put they are the *value category* of the data type.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

You should never store a reference to an r-value. Always examine the life time of the object before performing any operation and ensure the object stay alive till the operation is complete.

***Solution***

```
string a = "bar";
Foo foo(a);
```

Here a is l-value. But it is the user's responsibility to make sure that **a's** life scope is more than **foo**.

Or better

```
string a = "bar";
{
Foo foo(a);
}
```

This way you ensure that **foo** is destructed before **a**

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code crash and burn is because

```
: Foo(str.c_str())
```

is calling

```
Foo(const std::string& str);
```

and not

```
Foo(void* newData);
```

so you have infinite recursion. This is all bad and I advise you to rethink your approach, however just to get it running, cast the `str.c_str()` to `void *` explicitly:

```
: Foo((void *)str.c_str())
```

And of course make "bar" a stand alone `string` to avoid dealing with temporaries, and pass the string to constructor. This way the pointer will be valid until the scope with your `string` ends.

Demo: https://ideone.com/v7YfBX

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend not using void*
There are very few situations where you need to use void*, and you will loose any useful type information.

If you want to manipulate the bits directly within a std::string object, then from C++ 17, the data method on string gives access to the characters directly, without being constant.

If you want to make your code safer, just store std::string as a member variable of your Foo class, and use the methods available to you.
This will also mean you won't need to manually keep track of the internal pointer of a string passed from c_str or data method calls.

E.g. (partial example)

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& str);
    const char* getData() const;
    char* getData();

private:
    std::string m_str;
};

Foo::Foo(const std::string& str)
    : m_str(str)
{
}

const char* Foo::getData() const
{
    return m_str.c_str();
}

char* Foo::getData()
{
    // Note: Need C++ 17
    return m_str.data();
}
```