# Decorator design pattern : How to resolve error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator, lvalue

I was following [this](https://gist.github.com/raghunayak/3efef4bb730f053b5c6f) code to understand how to implement the decorator design as on internet everything is for JAVA but not much for cpp.

I am getting the error here:

```
Pizza &pizza = MexicanPizza();
```

I understand the left part is asking for const object. due to using reference which should not change. but how to make `MexicanPizza()` as const??

How to make the below code workable. I am trying to understand Abstract class, virtual class and Decorator design by using the above mentioned link code but I am not able to make it work. Sorry if it's a silly question. I just started learning designing using oops concept.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824153/how-do-i-pass-a-stdstring-as-a-constructor-argument-and-store-the-c-string-it/50824663 
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

class Pizza{
    private: 
        std::string name;
        float price;

    public:
        // constructor
        Pizza(const std::string &name_, const float price_): name(name_), price(price_){

        }

        virtual ~Pizza(){

        }

        virtual float getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        virtual std::string getName(){
            return name;
        }

        // kind of pizza
        virtual void bake()=0;
};

// Inheritance
// chessePizza : type of pizza
class CheesePizza : public Pizza{
    public: 
        CheesePizza() : Pizza("Cheese", 100){

        }

        ~CheesePizza(){

        }

        void bake(){
            std::cout<<"Baking "<<getName()<<" Pizza." <<std::endl;
        }
};

// Inheritance
// mexicanPizza : type of pizza
class MexicanPizza : public Pizza{
    public: 
        MexicanPizza() : Pizza("Mexican", 200){

        }

        ~MexicanPizza(){

        }

        void bake(){
            std::cout<<"Baking "<<getName()<<" Pizza." <<std::endl;
        }
};

// Decorator (Topping over pizza)
// Create object for topping(extra cheese, brocoli etc) and also store what was the pizza base
// So I can add the price of base + topping price
// bake is here what was the pizza type
class PizzaToppings: public Pizza{
    // store reference for pizza object;
    Pizza &pizza; // address

    public:
        // PizzaToppings will be applied on type of pizza we are using
        // Will passs object of types of pizza to it.
        PizzaToppings(const std::string &toppingName, const float price, Pizza & pizza_type) :
            Pizza(toppingName, price), pizza(pizza_type) // Pizza &pizza = pizza_type
        {
            
        }

        virtual ~PizzaToppings(){
        }

        virtual float getPrice(){
            return pizza.getPrice();
        }

        virtual std::string getName(){
            return pizza.getName();
        }

        virtual void bake(){
            pizza.bake();
        }
};

// Create class for extra cheese -> This will enhance the property of topping
// Here we will derive topping class and customize it.
// will return the price of topping (selevted one) and the pizza base price

class ExtraCheeseTopping: public PizzaToppings {
    // baking is different
    void addExtraCheese(){
        std::cout<<"Added extra cheese to the pizza: ["<<PizzaToppings::getName() <<"]."<<std::endl;
    }

    public: // sending the base piiza type also
    ExtraCheeseTopping(Pizza &pizza): PizzaToppings("ExtraCheeseToppings", 15, pizza){

    }
    ~ExtraCheeseTopping(){

    }

    virtual float getPrice(){
        return PizzaToppings::getPrice() + Pizza::getPrice();
    }

    virtual std::string getName(){
        return Pizza::getName();
    }

    virtual void bake(){
        addExtraCheese();
        PizzaToppings::bake();
    }
};



int main(){
    Pizza &pizza = MexicanPizza();
    ExtraCheeseTopping mexicanPizzaWithCheese(pizza);
    mexicanPizzaWithCheese.bake();

    std::cout<< "Total Price: "<<mexicanPizzaWithCheese.getPrice()<<std::endl;

}
```

**Error:**

```
deco_pizza.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
deco_pizza.cpp:161:20: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Pizza&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Pizza’
  161 |     Pizza &pizza = MexicanPizza();
```

Comment: Why are you using references here? It should just be `MexicanPizza pizza;`.

Comment: @user17732522: Actually I use that convention only `<class name> <object name>` but on net I was finding this way of defining the object. and also in constructor everyone is defining in this way: `<data member>(<value>)` Thanks I will try to write in that way only which I know. Working now. I don't know what's the best practice to write OOPS code.

Comment: Don't try to learn C++ from random things you find on the net. Get a reputable book.

Comment: Regarding your design I don't think `PizzaTopping` should inherit `Pizza` but instead make it a member of `Pizza` - like `std::vector<Topping> m_toppings`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes I got your point. Everyone has different way of writing the code. Can you share some resource(blog) where I can learn system design- LLD (using cpp).

Comment: @Odysseus: Yes in some discussion I saw that point some one mentioned to use vector for toppings no point of inheritance. But almost all the tutorial that I follow has java code (which uses extends, abstract class .....) so having hard time understanding the concepts by using cpp. Actually I can't see a better example for implementing decorator design.

Comment: I am thinking to follow: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator (this blog only) for learning . Can anyone comment on it?